# How to have a scroll animation and image like this?

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, html5-canvas, web-frontend

I am a new frontend developer who is learning to make some interactive sites. Recently i found this website https://albinotonnina.com . This has some great scroll animations and images. how can one make sites like this? are those images made by canvas and also about that scroll animation?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom of the page there is a github link https://github.com/albinotonnina/albinotonnina.com/ now you should be able to find how its made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help npm scroll module. Here is the doc link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll